# I'd like make private pywinauto fork for single Qt6 class, where to start?

Tags: pywinauto, qt6, flowlayout

We have this class: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_layouts_flowlayout.html ported from Qt6 by developers on the top of Qt5  application which we testing and it not supported by pywinauto and not mapped in Win application tree. So, how can do the same trick in pywinauto? Is the any simple approach to do it base on original pywinauto code?

Any help or thoughts.

Comment: Technically it is possible to implement new backend for QML based on DLL injection. Maybe this backend can obtain this information, but I'm not sure 100% it will help. There is even no noticeable prototype yet. Just a technology. Maybe app developers can deep dive into Qt6 code of this class and support its connection to UI Automation API providers (it is typically must be done by UI component developers). But I have no experience with providers, only with clients ("uia" backend).